# In Excel VBA, how can I format a substring within a string having the substring in an adjacent cell? It should not be hardcoded

Tags: excel, vba, format

using VBA in Excel, how can I make a substring bold within a string in a cell.

For example: I have "This is a test" in cell A1 and another string "is a" in an adjacent cell, B1.

The macro should scan the selected cell (A1) for the substring in B1 and make it bold within A1.

The result, after the format, should be "This **is a** test".

Like in the example below

[Sheet reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCuSX.png)

So, two important points:

The macro should be applied only for selected cells, being the substring adjacent to the right of the cell. Also, for now, bad performance is not an issue, also the substring might contain symbols and number that SHOULD also be formated.

Comment: Start with `InStr`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question to make it more clear. I'm completely noob to VBA, so if possible, If you could elaborate it with the full code. Thanks!